# How to check the return value of the recv() and send() using TCP protocol in perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, recv

I wrote the sample `client and server` program using `TCP protocol` in Perl.
So I used `send()` and `recv()` function.
In that I tried to get the return value of `recv()` function.
The sample code is,

```
my $return_value;
 $return_value = recv($client_socket, $data, 50, 0);
 print "return value is: $return_value\n";
```

When I execute my code, it doesn't print any value.
For example:

```
return value is:
```

After that I read the below link, even though I didn't get any return value.
[return value of recv() function in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579477/return-value-of-recv-function-in-perl)

How could I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/recv.html   recv - return address of the sender if scket's protocol supports this

Comment: The return value of `recv()` is a binary value that you have to pass to `Socket::unpack_sockaddr_in()` to obtain the IP address and port. I suppose it will usually print as gibberish but it may be that it just didn't contain any printable characters in your case. You can try piping your output to `xxd` to see those. That said, while it can be mae to work `recv()` isn't actually the function of choice for TCP servers. You can just use `print()` and `<>` for line based communication or `read()`/`write()` for fancier things.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably undef, indicating an error occurred<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
use Socket qw( unpack_sockaddr_in );

defined($return_value)
   or die("Can't recv: $!\n");

my ($peer_port, $peer_addr) = unpack_sockaddr_in($return_value);
```

You already know the address and port of the peer with which you are communicating, so this isn't very useful. This brings up the question of why are you using `recv` (instead of `sysread`) with connected streaming protocols like TCP? Do you realize you will sometimes get less than the `50` characters you requested?

---

1. Always use `use strict; use warnings 'all';`! If `$return_value` is undef, `"return value is: $return_value\n"` would have warned.

Comment: yes, I have used the `use strict` and `use warnings`. But it didn't warn me, also It didn't print any value